# Type does not name a type or error: field has incomplete type

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, incomplete-type

Im not sure why I am getting this error..."error: field 'config' has incomplete type". I have tried to do forward declaration and including the headers using #include...Im just trying to include fConfig in fInstance...

```cpp
#ifndef FINSTANCE_H
#define FINSTANCE_H

//#include "fConfig.h"
#include <vector>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class fConfig;

class fInstance
{
public:
    pid_t pid;
    fConfig config;
    vector<string> notes;
    vector<time_t> times;

    fInstance();
    virtual ~fInstance();
};

#endif // FINSTANCE_H





#ifndef FCONFIG_H
#define FCONFIG_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "JWDSFork.h"
#include "fInstance.h"

using namespace std;

class fConfig
{
    private:
        pid_t pid, w;

    public:
        pid_t cPid;
        string name;

        int group;
        int instanceId;
        int numInstance;
        int tries;

        bool reply;
        bool debug;
        bool service;
        bool currentlyRunning;

        time_t startTime;
        time_t endTime;

        string path;

        fConfig();
        virtual ~fConfig();

        void start();
        string intToString(int);
        char* stringToChar(string);
};

#endif // FCONFIG_H
```

**EDIT: Added changes**

```
#ifndef FINSTANCE_H
#define FINSTANCE_H

#include "fConfig.h"
#include <vector>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//class fConfig;

class fInstance
{
public:
    pid_t pid;
    fConfig* config;
    vector<string> notes;
    vector<time_t> times;

    fInstance();
    virtual ~fInstance();
};

#endif // FINSTANCE_H




#ifndef FCONFIG_H
#define FCONFIG_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "JWDSFork.h"
//#include "fInstance.h"

using namespace std;

class fConfig
{
    private:
        pid_t pid, w;

    public:
        pid_t cPid;
        string name;

        int group;
        int instanceId;
        int numInstance;
        int tries;

        bool reply;
        bool debug;
        bool service;
        bool currentlyRunning;

        time_t startTime;
        time_t endTime;

        string path;

        fConfig();
        virtual ~fConfig();

        void start();
        string intToString(int);
        char* stringToChar(string);
};

#endif // FCONFIG_H
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `#include "fConfig.h"` in `fInstance.h` and you don't need to include `fInstance.h` in `fConfig.h` because it appears that you are not using the type `fInstance` in `fConfig.h`.

When you forward declare a type compiler doesn't know the memory layout of that type and so it treats the type as an **Incomplete type** & the compiler cannot do any operations for which it needs to know the memory layout of that type.

You create an instance of `fConfig` after forward declaring it, to do that compiler needs to know the memory layout of `fConfig` but since you just forward declared it, it doesn't know that and hence complains.

Comment: @op: Forwarding declarations are useful when you are only using references or pointers to that datatype. Since you are using complete instances, you need the complete definition.

Comment: @Als so creating the instance is using new? i thought that calling fConfig config declared an instance?

Comment: @Spidey how do I fully declare this instance?

Comment: @JonH: It declares an member to the class, but the compiler needs to estimate the amount of memory that will be needed to store an object of type `fConfig` inside `fInstance`.How does the compiler know how much memory `fInstance` object will need? By summing up memory needed for all members of `fInstance`, so..

Comment: @Als so am i supposed to do something  `fConfig * config;`???? and if so how do I access the members of that class in cpp?

Comment: @JonH: Did you try the solution in the first para of the above answer?

Comment: @Als yes then it tells me that 'fConfig' does not name a type

Comment: @JonH: I don't think you did what is said, Please check again.Only `fInstance` needs to include `fConfig`, `fConfig` does not need to include `fInstance`.

Comment: @Als I took out the `#include "finstance.h"` declaration in fConfig and uncommented `#include "fConfig.h"` in finstance...

Comment: @Als so if I include fInstance.h in another header and need to access its members - how would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the full definition of `fConfig` before that of `fInstance`. The forward declaration won't do because your `fInstance` has an `fConfig` data member, so the full type is necessary:

in `fConfig.h`:

```
#ifndef FCONFIG_H
#define FCONFIG_H

class fConfig {
  // as in original
};

#endif
```

in `fInstance.h`:

```
#ifndef FINSTANCE_H
#define FINSTANCE_H

#include "fConfig.h" // need to include to get full type

class fInstance {
  // as in original
};

#endif
```

Comment: ok what does the full definition mean...do i need to use new?

Comment: @JonH no, not at all. Just put all the `fConfig` stuff before `fInstance`, and remove the `fInstance.h` include from `fConfig.h`.

Comment: am i declaring it outside the scope of the class?

Comment: when i do that it says that fConfig does not name a type

Comment: @JonH you must be doing something else wrong. What I suggested compiles, see http://ideone.com/0ndpx

Comment: how does this work when there is no declaration of fConfig in fInstance? did you comment out `#include "fConfig.h"` for use with ideone?

Comment: @JonH I commented it out because in the ideone sample the `fConfig.h` code is already pasted in. If I hade separate header files, I would have left that include uncommented.